# Use sudo: true with single element of build matrix in travis.ci?

Tags: travis-ci

I use and love the Travis CI continuous integration for an open source project on GitHub. I like the fast container builds, so I set `sudo: false` globally on my script.

However, in one particular build of my build matrix I want to spin up my own a docker container, so I think I need `sudo: true` here. Does this mean that I need to use `sudo: true` for all of my builds or is there some way around this?  I would like to set `sudo: true` for just one build. Alternatively, is it possible to have multiple `.travis.yml` scripts in the same GitHub repository?

Comment: IIRC the sudo true/false flag sets whether you're getting to run your builds on a fast (Dockerized) instance or you're using their older infrastructure.  I'm guessing all tests are run on one container.

Comment: Why do you need sudo?

Comment: I want to spin up my own docker container.  Presumably different elements in the build matrix are isolated from each other, so I don't think that they're running in the same instance of a container.

Comment: You'll [need](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/docker/) `sudo: required`. As *Aron* mentioned all builds run in one container.

Comment: [Here](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/workers/standard-infrastructure/) they mention the standard vs [container based](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/workers/container-based-infrastructure) build environment.

Answer (score 3):

As shown in the [numpy .travis.yml script](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/.travis.yml#L5) you can specify `sudo: true` on a per-element basis.

```
  include:
    - python: 2.7
      sudo: true
      dist: trusty
      env: ...
    - python: 2.7
      env: ...
```